# Joomla Database Problem

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, joomla1.5

I am a beginner to Joomla, I have installed Joomla 1.5 in my server with Fantastico including sample data, also i have installed joomla in my local server. I Don't know how to upload this project from local to real server, when i completed my project , i have exported my database and import this Database in to real server after deleting all tables from real data base. But everyday this database data automatically changed to old sample data? I don't know how to fix this problem. Please any one help me!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used Fantastico to install Joomla, but:

1. To copy a Joomla installation from a server to another you'll need to:

   - Copy the content of your webroot (be careful about permissions)
   - Adjust the config parameters from the config.php or through the admin panel
   - Dump the database from the old website and import it into the new one.
2. My feeling is that you're trying to "install" Joomla again on the real server, and during the installation you're confirming the creation of the sample data (this will override the existing tables).
3. Are you sure you're using the right database name in your real server? Maybe you have two or more...